# Is there an accessible builtin class to apply route values to a route template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, templates, .net-core, routes

Is there an accessible builtin class that can take a route template and apply values over it. I could parse and apply myself but I'd rather use a builtin if available.

Given a template such as:

```
api/[controller]/{action=index}
```

and values:

```
controller      foo
action          bar
```

returns

```
api/foo/bar
```

or with values:

```
controller      baz
```

returns

```
api/baz/index
```

Currently on asp.net core 3.1

Comment: I noticed there's a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Template.TemplateBinder` class that seems like it would do it, but I don't know how to get access to an instance of one.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I could inject a `TemplateBinderFactory` into my controller and create an instance of the `TemplateBinder` class. Then use the `BindValues()` method to apply the templates.

I'll want to make some tweaks for my needs, but this is basically it.

```cs
private readonly TemplateBinderFactory templateBinderFactory;

private string? ParseRouteTemplate(string? template, IDictionary<string, string> routeValues)
{
    if (template == null) return template;
    var binder = templateBinderFactory.Create(RoutePatternFactory.Parse(template));
    return binder.BindValues(new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues));
}
```

The binder doesn't quite fit my reqs in the question as it seems to be trying to return usable URIs, not necessarily just blindly substitute the values like I wanted. In this case, I could just read through the parsed `RoutePattern` and generate the string.

Answer (score 0):

Before dotnet 3.0 you don't have a `TemplateBinderFactory`, so if you're bound to an earlier version (like me), see [TemplateBinderTests.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/2.2.0/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tests/Template/TemplateBinderTests.cs) for sample usage of `TemplateBinder`, e.g.

```cs
// obtain template text from somewhere
// in my case it was a HttpMethodAttribute.Template
var routeTemplate = TemplateParser.Parse(templateText);
var pool = new DefaultObjectPoolProvider().Create(new UriBuilderContextPooledObjectPolicy());
var templateBinder = new TemplateBinder(UrlEncoder.Default, pool, routeTemplate, defaults: null);
var values = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteValueDictionary();
// set values, e.g. values.Add("...", ...);
var path = templateBinder.BindValues(values);
```